# Error: cannot find module 'web 3'

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, web3-providers

When I am running npm run test (mocha), I am getting this message.
 Using following: npm install --save mocha ganache-cli web3@1.0.0-beta.26
 Please advice.

```
> smart@1.0.0 test C:\Smart
> mocha

Error: Cannot find module 'web3'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Smart\test\inbox.test.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Smart\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:253:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Smart\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:250:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Smart\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:577:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Smart\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:591:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! smart@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the smart@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Not too familiar with mocha testing outside of truffle, but have you tried uninstalling and then npm install web3 ?

Comment: Absolutely.No matter what version of web3 I install, it still producing the same error.

Comment: @SergeiStadnik Can you put the first lines of the failing test `inbox.test.js`? ie the lines where you to try to require 'web3'.

Comment: I rewrote the application, it had some syntax errors.Now I am getting a different error:

Error: Cannot find module 'ganache-cli'

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows, open up your terminal as administrator and run the following command:

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools